# YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player getting error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have trouble using the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` inside a (Support)`ViewPager`. Everything works fine except when i come resume method youtube player playing few seconds, and then it will be paused. Getting error.

My Layout..

```
   ..

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerCardList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:dividerHeight="8dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

My Code :

```
private void setYoutubePlayer() {

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment)
            .addToBackStack(youTubePlayerFragment.getClass().getName()).commitAllowingStateLoss();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

                player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);
                player.play();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            // YouTube error
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in layout, from what i remember, YouTube Player doesn't permit any view staying over it, neither invisible nor transparent. In order to make this visible in your device, enable layout bounds in developer option (warning with paddings and margins). So, i think you must make sure there are no other views in top of your youtube layout.

Hope it helps you.